# I want to convert x86 Linux shellcode with system calls to ARM Linux system calls

Tags: assembly, x86, arm, shellcode

I want to convert Intel x86 assembly code to ARM.
I do not know how to use the stack.

I wrote a call to execve using an `int 0x80` system call for 32-bit x86 Linux.
However, ARM uses svc or swi.

But I do not know how to use something like this:
`push 0x0068732f` and `push 0x6e69622f`

```
.globl main
main:

push 0x0068732f
push 0x6e69622f

mov edx, 0
mov ecx, 0
mov ebx, esp
mov eax, 11
int 0x80

mov ebx, 0
mov eax, 1
int 0x80
```

The syscall on arm expects to use the swi to look like this:

```
.global _start

_start:
    ?????
    mov r7, #11
    swi #0

_exit:
    mov r7, #1
    swi #0
```

I want to use the stack push method rather than the .ascii method.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?  Is this shell code?

Comment: raspberry pi b+ armv7l, raspbian linux

Comment: Yes I’m just practicing how to create shellcode.

Comment: Note that while it is possible to push strings to the stack, it is just much easier to load a PC relative address.  Would this be ok with you?

Comment: ARM doesn't have push-immediate.  You need to construct data in registers before you push them.

Answer (score 3):

`man syscall`

```
    arch/ABI    instruction           syscall #  retval  error    Notes
   ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   arm/EABI    swi 0x0               r7         r0      -
   x32         syscall               rax        rax     -        [5]


   arch/ABI      arg1  arg2  arg3  arg4  arg5  arg6  arg7  Notes
   ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   arm/EABI      r0    r1    r2    r3    r4    r5    r6
```

See: [ARM constants](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/how-to-load-constants-in-assembly-for-arm-architecture)

```
.global _start

.equ    label1, 0x0068732f
.equ    label2, 0x6e69622f

_start:
 movw    r3, #:lower16:label1
 movt    r3, #:upper16:label1
 movw    r2, #:lower16:label2
 movt    r2, #:upper16:label2
 push    {r2,r3}

 mov R3, #0
 mov R2, #0
 mov R1, #0
 mov r0, sp
 mov r7, #11
 swi #0

_exit:
 mov r0, #0
 mov r7, #1
 swi #0
```

---

Here is another example,

```
asm mov r0, #0
push {r0}
movw r1, #0x6548 @ He 
movt r1, #0x6c6c @ ll 
movw r2, #0x576f @ oW 
movt r2, #0x726f @ or 
movw r3, #0x646c @ ld 
movt r3, #0x0a32 @ 2\n
push {r1,r2,r3}  @ move register 'string' to stack.
@ write(unsigned int fd, const char *buf, size_t count) 
mov r0, #1  @ stdout 
mov r1, sp  @ load string from stack 
mov r2, #12 @ length 
mov r7, #4  @ write() syscall number
swi #0      @ syscall
```

Most modern ARM CPUs will support `movw`/`movt`.  There are other ways to do this.  But they are like '.ascii' as ARM code can contain constants.  That is the old style as discussed in the blog above.  I might have some ordering mixed up in the code above, but I think it is right.

Comment: A common technique in x86 shellcode is to put an ASCII string after the code (still as part of the payload), and use a PC-relative way to get a pointer to it into a register.  Then the very end of it can contain a `0` byte that terminates the shellcode (which has to be free from zero bytes so it can overflow a buffer via `strcpy()` or something).  That's more efficient than 2 bytes of data per 4 bytes of instruction.  (vs. 32-bit x86 with 4 string bytes per 5 bytes of instructions for `push imm32`)

Comment: You can also create a zero in a register and then store a zero byte into the middle of your payload, to create multiple shorter implicit-length C strings.  To create a zero in a reg, you're going to want something like `eor r3,r3` instead of `mov` an immediate zero.  But the OP didn't ask for that, or avoid zeros in their x86 machine code, so +1 for converting the system calls.

Comment: I definitely agree that the `.ascii` method is more efficient (esp on ARM).  No need to `push`, just grab the PC-relative address and put it in r0 with `add r0, pc, #offset`.  The string can easily be put after the `exit()` call.

Comment: Don't you want `add` for address calc, not a PC-relative *load*?

Comment: Sure.  The `ldr r0, =label` is common but not needed with  `adr r0, bin_shell_string` working in this case with a short distance.  Both work.

Comment: ```asm 
    mov     r0, #0
    push   {r0}
    movw        r1, #0x6548     @ He
    movt        r1, #0x6c6c     @ ll
    movw        r2, #0x576f     @ oW
    movt        r2, #0x726f     @ or
    movw        r3, #0x646c     @ ld
    movt        r3, #0x0a32 @ 2\n

    push    {r1,r2,r3}

    @ write(unsigned int fd, const char *buf, size_t count)
    mov     r0, #1       @ stdout
    mov     r1, sp       @ load string from stack
    mov     r2, #12      @ length
    mov     r7, #4       @ write()
    swi     #0           @ syscall

```
It's what I exactly mean! Thanks