# Why does this shellcode cause the target to hang?

Tags: assembly, arm, shellcode

I'll preface this by saying I'm not too familiar with assembly on ARM.

Basically, I'm trying to write shellcode similar to [this](http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-904.php). The code works just fine, but I'm trying to make some modifications to see how it works. Here is the target program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char payload[34];
    int len=fread(payload, 1, 34, stdin);

    printf("Length: %d\n", len);
    (*(void(*)()) payload) ();
}
```

I compile the assembly from that link, slice out the shellcode into a file, and then I send it to stdin like so:

```
(cat shellcode; echo ps) | ./target
```

Which yields:

```
Length: 34
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3565 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
 3854 pts/3    00:00:00 sh
 3856 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
```

When I do the same with the shellcode I wrote, the program hangs taking up 100% cpu. If I step through it enough times in gdb I get the following over and over:

```
(gdb) s
55      in dl-addr.c
```

This is the assembly code I wrote:

```
.LC0:
        .global main
main:
        mov     r2, #0
        mov     r1, #0
        ldr     r0, =string
        bl      execve
string:
        .asciz "/bin/sh"
```

I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `si` (or, in full, `stepi`) command, not `s` (which is `step`). The latter operates on source lines, while the former works with instructions. And then use the `disas` (or `disassemble`) command to see where you are in the assembly view of your program+shellcode. Or, instead of `disas`, you may find `x/10i $pc` more useful (where 10 is number of instructions to disassemble).

Answer (score 1):

`bl execve` is trying to call a 'C' library `execve` and not the Linux syscall. Use,

```
mov r7, #11
swi #0
```

instead of `bl execve` as per [writing ARM shellcode](https://azeria-labs.com/writing-arm-shellcode). Also, using `adr string` instead of `ldr =string` will save four bytes and make the shell code more robust (PIC).

I modified the assembly code to the following and it works!

```
.LC0:
        .global main
main:
        mov     r2, #0
        mov     r1, #0
        adr     r0, string
        mov r7, #11
        swi #0
string:
        .asciz "/bin/sh"
```

Comment: [Shell code with ARM Linux syscalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826583/i-want-to-convert-x86-linux-shellcode-with-system-calls-to-arm-linux-system-call) is a similar question, but the string is part of the code as opposed to appended.  In between this and an [Ascii printable exploit](http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-904.php).